# Laravel Query Builder join doesn't affect query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to build in search functionality in my application (Laravel 5.1), but my join doesn't seem to do anything to the resulting query. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
$query = InvoiceHeader::where('customer_code_id', '=', Auth::user()->customer_code_id);

$query->join('invoice_types', 'invoice_headers.invoice_type_id', '=', 'invoice_types.id')
      ->where('invoice_types.name', '<>', array_search('Faktura', InvoiceHeader::INVOICE_TYPES));

$invoices = $query->paginate(15);
```

Resulting query:

> select count(*) as aggregate from `invoice_headers` where `customer_code_id` = 1 and (`invoice_types`.`name` <> 380)

Resulting response:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice_types.name' in 'where clause'

This is the query I was hoping to see:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from invoice_headers 
inner join invoice_types 
   on invoice_headers.invoice_type_id = invoice_types.id
where customer_code_id = 1 
   and (invoice_types.name <> 380)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = InvoiceHeader::where('customer_code_id', '=', Auth::user()->customer_code_id);
```

you need to store the query in a variable.

```
$query = $query->join('invoice_types', 'invoice_headers.invoice_type_id', '=', 'invoice_types.id')
      ->where('invoice_types.name', '<>', array_search('Faktura', InvoiceHeader::INVOICE_TYPES));

$invoices = $query->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **JOIN** with **invoice_types** table if you want to filter on **invoice_types.name**.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. Please take a look again!

Comment: Looks like it's losing the join. Try to first do the join and then apply 2 where conditions.

Comment: I tried adding this:
        ->where('invoice_types.name', '<>', array_search('Faktura', InvoiceHeader::INVOICE_TYPES));

But it just added another "and `invoice_types`.`name` <> 380" to the query

Comment: Well, that's what you asked eloquent to do so it's no suprise. Have you tried first doing the join and then applying those 2 where constraints?

Comment: I tried separating the join and where into two statements before, if that's what you meant. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Try doing dd($query->toSql()) and paste the query. I tested the code a very similar query and it works

Comment: I tried it now. It didn't throw me any errors, but it also returned all the rows I wanted to filter away. I guess this means that the joins have to be added before any wheres?

Comment: It depends. Could you update your question with the SQL you need to be generated? It will be much simpler this way than trying to guess your intention based on a builder query that doesn't work :)

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: It's not a correct SQL. "join invoice_types array_search", there is no JOIN or WHERE conditions

Comment: lmfao apparently I couldn't copy while editing my reply (Way to go SO) so I just pasted the last thing I had copied. Sorry about that, it's fixed

Comment: And what is the join condition? I don't see it in the query, just WHEREs

Comment: Can you please take another look? I think I changed it since you first saw

Comment: $query = $query->join('invoice_types', 'invoice_headers.invoice_type_id', '=', 'invoice_types.id')
      ->where('invoice_types.name', '<>', array_search('Faktura', InvoiceHeader::INVOICE_TYPES));

Comment: And what does array_search return?